# MySQL (InnoDB): Cannot drop database nor create it

Tags: mysql, innodb, corruption

When trying (InnoDB):

```
DROP DATABASE mydatabase;
```

I almost inmediately get:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I checked the timeouts and they are far enough from being short (600 seconds) so I stopped MySQL, removed `mydatabase` folder and started MySQL again. Then I re-created my DB and loaded it from a dump:

```
mysql -u <user> -p mydatabase < Dump.sql
```

But the process failed once and again due to some already existing table (though I'm sure it is not duplicated in the dump file), so at this point I don't really know what to do and whether I'm facing some InnoDB corruption issue (logs do not show anything related).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Messing around in the db directory by hand is not a good idea for InnoDB. I would guess it is related to this [Error when dropping InnoDB database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/error-when-dropping-innodb-database)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the proper link. I'll write what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, as (credits go for him) @t.niese's link points out, I quit trying to drop the (corrupted) DB and ended up recovering the dump into another DB, just changing its name. Fortunately I didn't need to have the same name, so I skipped the long process pointed out at that link. But alas it seems the corrupted database will stay in the `ibdata1` file.